# how to run github cli in container as random user

Tags: docker, github-cli

I have managed to install github cli in container but I am unable to run it as a random user (open shift does runs containers as random user due to security)
What directories should I create/chmod/chown beforehand to make it work?

THANK YOU!

docker file:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/download/v1.0.0/gh_1.0.0_linux_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i gh_*_linux_amd64.deb
RUN chmod g+rwx -R /usr/local/bin/gh  # <- not enough
RUN gh version
```

container log:

```sh
...
Step 7/28 : RUN gh version
 ---> Running in 09d1ffbfcc02
Welcome to GitHub CLI!

To authenticate, please run `gh auth login`.
You can also set the GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable, if preferred.
The command '/bin/sh -c gh version' returned a non-zero code: 4
`/` is not writable.
...
```

Comment: Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/issues/295) can help you.

Comment: there is a bug in the docs, it is ```gh --version``` not ```gh version```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug in the [docs](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/source.md), it is
`gh --version`
not
`gh version`

also `RUN chmod g+rwx -R /usr/local/bin/` before mentioned command helps.